# Add hours derived from subquery to my timestamp

Tags: netezza

My below query adds four days to my current time, but instead I need to add four hours to it. I am adding the UTC offset.

```
select ,REQUEST_TIME,
to_char(timestamp((REQUEST_TIME - cast(select extract(hours from
(select TIMEZONE(current_timestamp, 'America/New_York','Etc/GMT')) - current_timestamp)))) ,
'YYYY-MM-DD HH24') as request_time_EST from Table
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! . Please edit your post and format it well for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are running into here is that the result of the EXTRACT of the hours is returned as an integer (see B1 below), and then subtracting that from REQUEST_TIME is subtracting that number of days giving a result you did not expect or want (see C2 below).

What you are looking for, I believe, would require casting the B1 value to an interval of hours (see D1 below).

select request_time,
TIMEZONE(current_timestamp, 'America/New_York','Etc/GMT') -

```
current_timestamp A1,
extract(hours from TIMEZONE(current_timestamp, 'America/New_York','Etc/GMT') - current_timestamp) B1,
request_time - extract(hours from TIMEZONE(current_timestamp, 'America/New_York','Etc/GMT') - current_timestamp) C1,
request_time - cast( extract(hours from TIMEZONE(current_timestamp, 'America/New_York','Etc/GMT') - current_timestamp) || ' hours ' as interval) D1
from table1;

TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)-> from table1;
    REQUEST_TIME     |    A1    | B1 |     C1     |         D1          
---------------------+----------+----+------------+---------------------
 2016-01-31 12:00:00 | 04:00:00 |  4 | 2016-01-27 | 2016-01-31 08:00:00
(1 row)
```

You mention using subselects in your question and in your example code, I but I didn't see a need for a subselect in this case.

Comment: Hi Scott, I have a field in my table as REQUEST_TIME which is in UTC format. I need to dynamically convert this to NY time by subtracting either 4 or 5, depending on the daly light saving. This query gives me the current offset (4) : select extract(hours from
(select TIMEZONE(current_timestamp, 'America/New_York','Etc/GMT')) - current_timestamp.....I need this offset to be added to the REQUEST_TIME field. If i straightawy do a subtraction it subtracts 4 days, but i want to subtract 4 hours. I know the cast command with 4 interval but how can i pass this derived value to my query.

Comment: Ok, I completely misunderstood your question, but I think I get what you want now.  scrapping/reworking my answer.